# Merge two table in new table with random records of two tables - c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, merge

I have 2 tables with one column in sql and I want to merge data into one new table which have 2 columns,

- First table has one row and second row should go 'V86'
- 2nd table has one row and second row should go  'V2T'

I need to merge 700 records total in new table 328 from first table and 372 from 2nd table. there should be 2 sets 350 each with 164 record from first table and 186 records from second table with good randomness of records.

I wrote this code first batch of 350 records have nice randomness but second batch of 350 has 1-164 'V86' records and 165-350 'V2T' [No Randomness]

its the same loop which runs twice, I tried but couldn't figure it out. Can anyone help me out?

```
private void QUEMerge()
{
    DataTable ae50braQUE = aeBL.AE50BraQUE();
    DataTable ae50SwimQUE = aeBL.AE50SwimQUE();

    int rowAE50BraQue = 0;
    int rowAE50SwimQue = 0;

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    int ttlque = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        int temp1 = 0;
        int temp2 = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < 350; j++)
        {
            rowAE50BraQue = rowAE50BraQue + 3;
            rowAE50SwimQue = rowAE50SwimQue + 4;

            for (; a < rowAE50BraQue; a++)
            {
                if (temp1 >= 164 || ttlque >= 700)
                {
                    break;
                }
                DataRow dr = ae50braQUE.Rows[a];
                aeBL.MergeQUE(dr["Coupon"].ToString(), "V86");
                temp1++;
                ttlque++;
            }

            for (; b < rowAE50SwimQue; b++)
            {
                if (temp2 >= 186 || ttlque >= 700)
                {
                    break;
                }
                DataRow dr = ae50SwimQUE.Rows[b];
                aeBL.MergeCouponsQUE(dr["Coupon"].ToString(), "V2T");
                temp2++;
                ttlque++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my fixed working code..

```
private void QUEMerge()
{
        DataTable ae50braQUE = aeBL.AE50BraQUE();
        DataTable ae50SwimQUE = aeBL.AE50SwimQUE();         

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        //int ttlque = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            int rowAE50BraQue = 0;
            int rowAE50SwimQue = 0;

            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;

            int temp1 = 0;
            int temp2 = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < 350; j++)
            {
                rowAE50BraQue = rowAE50BraQue + 3;
                rowAE50SwimQue = rowAE50SwimQue + 4;

                for (; a < rowAE50BraQue; a++)
                {
                    if (temp1 >= 164)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    DataRow dr = ae50braQUE.Rows[x];
                    aeBL.MergeCouponsQUE(dr["Coupon"].ToString(), "V86");
                    temp1++;
                    x++;
                    //ttlque++;
                }

                for (; b < rowAE50SwimQue; b++)
                {
                    if (temp2 >=186)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    DataRow dr = ae50SwimQUE.Rows[y];
                    aeBL.MergeCouponsQUE(dr["Coupon"].ToString(), "V2T");
                    temp2++;
                    y++;
                   // ttlque++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using only t-sql:

```
WITH cte as
(
    SELECT a.a, b.b, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.a ORDER BY NEWID()) as rn
        FROM (VALUES ('x'),('y'),('z')) AS a(a)
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')) as b(b)
)
--INSERT INTO NewTable(a, b)
    SELECT TOP(5) a, b
        FROM cte
        WHERE rn in (1,2)
        ORDER BY NEWID();
```

where `a` - `table1`, `b` - `table2`, `TOP(5)` - in your case `TOP(700)`

p.s. this query is completely independent, so you can run it to test results